# Multiple ajax calls on same file to execute different code in same file?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, pdo

I'm still pretty new to server side scripting and ajax. What I'm wondering is can I make multiple ajax calls to the same file but with my ajax calls, only read a certain script within that file to execute for that particular ajax call? Reason I'm wondering this is because when I make a ajax call, it parses the entire code of my script that it's making the ajax call too instead of the particular code that's inside with my other ajax call scripts.

Now, I can solve this problem entirely by simply making a new file and pointing my ajax calls to separate files but wouldn't this considered to be bad architecture? For example, 1 ajax call to editusers.js another one for deleteusers.js why not simply have all different ajax calls in one file?

Here is my code, I'm using bootstrap data tables with server side rendering PDO not mysqli. The first ajax call is to query all records within my table and the second ajax call is for functionality in regards to editing a users record within the table itself. However, I stopped at editing a users record functionality cause I was wondering if it was possible if I could achieve this?

**HTML & JavaScript**

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#userDetails').DataTable({
     "scrollY": "400px",
     "scrollCollapse": true,
     "processing": true,
     "serverSide": true,
     "ajax": {
      "url": "../user-actions-script.php",
      "type": "post",
     },
     "deferRender": true,
   oLanguage: {sProcessing: "<i class='fas fa-spinner fa-3x' id='loader'></i>"},
    });

 $(document).on('click', 'i.fas.fa-edit', function(e){
  $.ajax({
   url: '../user-actions-script.php',
   success: function(){
    console.log('works');
   }
  })
 });

});
</script>

<body>
 <div class="fluid-container">
  <header>
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark"></nav>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
   <h2>User Actions</h2>

   <div class="userdetailsContainer">
    <table class="table table-dark table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="userDetails">
     <thead>
      <!-- adding this in later -->
     </thead>
    </table>
   </div>
   <!-- Edit Actions Modal -->
   <!-- Modal -->
   <div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
       <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
           <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h5>
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
             <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
           </button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
           <div class="editHeader">
            <i class="fas fa-edit fa-2x"></i>
            <span>Edit User</span>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
            <form
             method="POST"
       
             >
             <label for="email">Email:</label>
             <input
               type="email"
        class="form-control"
        name="email"
             >
       <label for="fullName">Full Name:</label>
       <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        name="fullName"
       >
       <label for="area">area:</label>
       <select
        class="form-control"
        name="area"
        id="area"
       >
        <?php include ("_global/includes/login_select_options-approved.php") ;?>
       </select>
       <label for="requestor">Requestor:</label>
       <select
        class="form-control"
        name="requestor"
        id="requestor"
       >
        <?php include ("_global/includes/select_options.php") ;?>
       </select>
         </div>
            </form>
            <button
             type="submit"
             class="btn btn-primary">
             Save changes
            </button>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

**PHP PDO / Ajax script**

```js
<?php 
 include "_global/includes/config.php";

 // Set all fetch requests as an object by default
 $dbo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

 // Custom Usergroups Inputs
 $admin = 'ADMIN';
 $emptyValues = '';
 $adminLive = 'ADMIN-live';
 $adminType = 'ADMIN_US_Type';
 $customusDomestic = 'US_domestic';
 $adminChina = 'China_admin';
 $adminIndia = 'India_admin';
 $adminCustom = 'ADMIN_custom';
 $customusaustinCulver = 'US_Austin_Culver';
 $customuschinaTokyo = 'US_China_Tokyo';
 $customcorkuaeBayarea = 'Cork_UAE_BayArea';
 $customchinashanghaiBeijing = 'China_Shanghai_Beijing';
 $adminselfMoves = 'ADMIN_selfmoves';
 $adminmilanVienna = 'ADMIN-milan-vienna';
 $custombayareaSeattle = 'Bayarea_Seattle_admin';
 $custombayareaCulver = 'ADMIN_Culver_Bay';
 $customculverSingapore = 'ADMIN_Culver_Singapore';
 $customcanada = 'ADMIN_canada';

 // Datatable serverside processing script
 $request = $_REQUEST;
 $columns = array(
  0 => 'name',
  1 => 'email',
  2 => 'usergroup',
  3 => 'user',
  4 => 'DateAdded'
 );

 // Prepare the query
 $sqlAll = 'SELECT mem_id, email, name, usergroup, user, DateAdded
   FROM plus_signuptestdata
   WHERE usergroup NOT IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
    GROUP BY email
    ORDER BY dateAdded DESC';

 $stmt = $dbo->prepare($sqlAll);

 // Execute the query
 $stmt->execute([$admin,$emptyValues,$adminLive,$adminType,$customusDomestic,$adminChina,$adminIndia,$adminCustom,$customusaustinCulver,$customuschinaTokyo,$customcorkuaeBayarea,$customchinashanghaiBeijing,$adminselfMoves,$adminmilanVienna,$custombayareaSeattle,$custombayareaCulver,$customculverSingapore,$customcanada]);

 // Count Rows
 $rowCount = $stmt->rowCount();
 // Fetch the query
 $totalData = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 $totalFiltered = $rowCount;


 $sqlAll = "SELECT mem_id, email, name, usergroup, user, DateAdded ";
 $sqlAll .= " FROM plus_signuptestdata ";
 $sqlAll .= " WHERE usergroup NOT IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
 if(!empty($request['search']['value'])){
  $sqlAll .= " AND name LIKE '%".$request['search']['value']."%' ";

  $sqlAll .= " OR email LIKE '%".$request['search']['value']."%'";

 }
 // Order by with empty or without empty user string
 $sqlAll .=" ORDER BY ". $columns[$request['order'][0]['column']]." ".$request['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".$request['start']." ,".$request['length']."   ";

 $stmt = $dbo->prepare($sqlAll);
 // Execute the query
 $stmt->execute([$admin,$emptyValues,$adminLive,$adminType,$customusDomestic,$adminChina,$adminIndia,$adminCustom,$customusaustinCulver,$customuschinaTokyo,$customcorkuaeBayarea,$customchinashanghaiBeijing,$adminselfMoves,$adminmilanVienna,$custombayareaSeattle,$custombayareaCulver,$customculverSingapore,$customcanada]);

 $totalData = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


 $newData = array();
 // Convert all the data to UTF-8 unicode format.
 foreach($totalData as $item) {
  $nestedData=array(); 

  $nestedData[] = mb_convert_encoding($item['name'], 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
  $nestedData[] = mb_convert_encoding($item['email'], 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
  $nestedData[] = mb_convert_encoding($item['usergroup'], 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
  $nestedData[] = mb_convert_encoding($item['user'], 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
  $nestedData[] = mb_convert_encoding($item['DateAdded'], 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
  $nestedData[] = '<i class="fas fa-edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal" id="'.$item['mem_id'].'"></i> <i class="fas fa-trash" id="'.$item['mem_id'].'"></i>';
 
  $newData[] = $nestedData;
 }


 $json_data = array(
  "draw"            => intval( $request['draw']), 
  "recordsTotal"    => intval( $rowCount ),  
  "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ),
  "data"            => $newData  
 );

 echo json_encode($json_data);
  
  // This is fine but what happens when I need to make another ajax call to this file? It'll read all the contents of this script how can I make it to where it reads only certain code within the same file?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

but wouldn't this considered to be bad architecture? No, doing it your way would be bad architecture. Separate actions (delete.php,update.php,create.php) in different files it would be better and more maintainable, but im talking about the php part, Yes you can have on the same javascript  all your calls to those files
for example:

```
//crud.js

$("#delete_button").on('click', function(e){
        $.ajax({
            url: '../delete.php',
            success: function(){
                console.log('deleted');
            }
        })
    });

$("#update_button").on('click', function(e){
        $.ajax({
            url: '../update.php',
            success: function(){
                console.log('updated');
            }
        })
    });
$("#create_button").on('click', function(e){
        $.ajax({
            url: '../create.php',
            success: function(){
                console.log('created');
            }
        })
    });
```

Comment: Okay thank you for the advice I'll take this into consideration for the future.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the if block condition for executing the particular ajax call suppose you want to execute the first if block from first ajax call then you have to pass the parameters with ajax that your first if block condition is a true and same way for all the ajax calls.

PHP CODE

```
 <?php 
     if($_POST['DATA']=='FIRST'){
       all statements are here.
      }else if($_POST['DATA']=='SECOND'){
       all statements of second block is here.
      }else if($_POST['DATA']=='THIRD'){
        all statements of the third block are here.
      }   so on 
  ?>
```

AJAX CALL

```
  // First AJAX CALL for FIRST IF BLOCK
  $.ajax({
        url: 'please give php file url',
        data:{ DATA: 'FIRST' },
        success: function(){
            console.log('works');
        }
    });
  //  Second AJAX CALL for SECOND IF BLOCK
    $.ajax({
        url: 'please give php file url',
        data:{ DATA: 'SECOND' },
        success: function(){
            console.log('works');
        }
    });
  // so on
```

I Think, I'm on the right track :)

Comment: This is actually what I was looking for however, I think @Geomorillo response is more advised, I think it's better to diversify actions in different files rather than having it all in one file for all the actions. Nevertheless thank you for your response.